flashbot bundle to claim ico tokens
Does anyone have a flashbot bundle to claim ico tokens from a hacked wallet? Would love an example that has worked for them. Would need eth from third party wallet to fund the bundle. I do have someone who is helping me but we are getting stuck with the bundle not being picked up by the mempool.
